# Installing rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, linux, ubuntu, ruby-debug, linecache

I'll be very grateful id someone can explain me what does that mean:

```
ror@ubuntu:$ sudo gem install linecache19 -v '0.5.12'
ERROR:  Error installing linecache19:
    linecache19 requires Ruby version >= 1.9.2.
ror@ubuntu:$ ruby -v
ruby 1.9.3p194 (2012-04-20 revision 35410) [x86_64-linux]
```

As I understand 1.9.3 >= 1.9.2 ? Am I wrong?

Comment: Maybe your global Ruby Installation is a < 1.9.2 version, so when you use `sudo` to install your gems, it does not recognize the correct version.

Comment: after selecting rvm if permission issue comes try `rvmsudo`

Answer (score 0):

Just try RVM, as @Daniel pointed out, or even simpler, just use something like this:
https://github.com/joshfng/railsready

This automatically installs Rails on your ubuntu Machine:

```
wget --no-check-certificate https://raw.github.com/joshfng/railsready/master/railsready.sh && bash railsready.sh
```

Answer (score 0):

You are running the gem install command as sudo, but the `ruby -v` as your own user.
If you use `sudo ruby -v` you will probably get `ruby 1.8.7` as the version.

As suggested, use `rvm` and never install gems with sudo again.

Comment: No, ror@ubuntu:$ sudo ruby -v
ruby 1.9.3p194 (2012-04-20 revision 35410) [x86_64-linux]

Comment: check your `export` output for RUBY_VERSION